# How to add two vectors on three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Can't find out what am I missing....

Debuging a sample code I found these lines and dump it to console to understand what is going wrong:

```
        var intPosition = new THREE.Vector3( Math.floor(result.point.x), 0, Math.floor(result.point.z) );
        console.log(intPosition);
        brush.position = intPosition.clone().add(new THREE.Vector3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5) );
        console.log(brush.position);
```

but.......... the output is as follow (from firebug console):

```
Object { x=0, y=0, z=10, more... }
Object { x=0, y=0, z=0, more... }
```

from [three.js docs](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Math/Vector3):

```
.add ( v ) this
```

Adds v to this vector.

and [here](https://threejsdoc.appspot.com/doc/three.js/src.source/core/Vector3.js.html):

```
add: function ( v1, v2 ) {

    this.x = v1.x + v2.x;
    this.y = v1.y + v2.y;
    this.z = v1.z + v2.z;

    return this;

},
```

What's wrong? Is it the integer+float failling on js?

**EDIT NOTE:**

I don't know if it is relevant but this issue occurs on my current version (revision 71) of Three.js, working fine on older versions (r60 or lower).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use the .set() method of Vector3 class.

```
var brushPosition = intPosition.clone().add(new THREE.Vector3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5) );
brush.position.set(brushPosition.x, brushPosition.y, brushPosition.z);
```

You might also be able to use the copy function of Vector3 class.

```
brush.position.copy(intPosition.clone().add(new THREE.Vector3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5));
```

EDIT:
the reason is that the position property of object3D is non-writable. it may not be set with an assignment operator.

Comment: `brush.position.copy( intPosition ).addScalar( 0.5 );`